# Where is the associate tag/id for an Amazon account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's the info needed for API access:

```
access_key = <your access key>
secret_key = <your secret key>
associate_tag = <your associate id>
```

I know [here](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com) there is a value ending with `-20` but I'm not sure if I'm to include the 20 or exclude it? The documentation has no information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associate ID is also called the tracking ID and is available at the link posted above.

> The associate tag is the term used by the API for the ID of the account where clicks are tracked and sales commissions are credited. You can have several attached to your associate account for your own internal tracking reasons (for each marketing campaign or section of your website or whatever). When a user clicks the link supplied by the API with your associate tag embedded in the URL, that tracking ID is credited with that click in associate central.

Source: [Amazon Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230963&tstart=0)